# Display table with a possible join on some records

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables

Table one is a list of documents

**documents:**

```
+-------------+---------------+
| document_ID | document_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|    1        |   test.pdf    |
+-------------+---------------+
|    2        |  other.pdf    |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Table two is a list of users who have used that document. It is a 1-1 relationship - i.e. a user will only ever use a document ONCE (or not at all).

**documents_users:**

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| document_ID | user_ID       | has_read  | (other stuff) |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|    1        |   5           |     1     |      stuff    |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|    1        |   7           |     1     |      stuff    |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|    2        |   5           |     1     |      stuff    |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
```

When a user is browsing the list - I need to be able to show ALL documents, plus IF they have access it or not

So for example the desired output for user 5 in the example above is;

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| document_ID | document_name |  has_read | (other stuff) |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|    1        |   test.pdf    |     1     |      stuff    |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|    2        |  other.pdf    |     1     |      stuff    |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
```

while the desired output for user 7 is

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| document_ID | document_name |  has_read | (other stuff) |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|    1        |   test.pdf    |     1     |   stuff       |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|    2        |  other.pdf    |           |               |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
```

I tried doing a join along the lines of

```
$this->db->join('documents_users', 'documents_users.document_ID = documents.document_ID');
$this->db->where('documents_users.user_ID', '7');
return $this->get_all();
```

But this only returns the records that they has_read=1

I can see the problem is the "where" command - but I'm not sure what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a (left) outer join, with the filter criterion on `user_ID` moved into the join condition rather than being in a `WHERE` clause:

```
$this->db->join(
   'documents_users',
   'documents_users.document_ID = documents.document_ID
AND documents_users.user_ID = 7',
   'left'
);
```

Comment: eggyal - any ideas how I could run this same query - and only return documents a specific user has NOT read? I tried changing 'left' to 'inner' - and that gives me the documents they HAVE read. So I need to do a 'difference' between those two queries?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange: `$this->db->where('documents_users.has_read IS NULL');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to take [STRAIGHT_JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html):

```
SELECT a.document_ID, a.document_name, b.has_read,
FROM documents a 
     STRAIGHT_JOIN documents_users b
WHERE b.user_ID = 7;
```